# Why did Apache IoTDB installed by docker reported connection warning and sometimes need to be restarted?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

The Apache IoTDB I installed using docker requires repeated restart of the system. The restart message looks like `DataNode: 411 - Sending restart request to ConfigNode-leader`. Sometimes a warning message appears and the system has to be restart: `WARN o.a.i.d.p.c.ConfigNodeClient: 308 - Failed to connect to ConfigNode TEndPoint`, sometimes the system will normally execute after waiting. I want to know if this is normal for the startup process of IoTDB?

Answer (score 0):

The cluster settings of Apache IoTDB has two kinds of nodes, ConfigNode and DataNode. However, there is only one main process in docker, so the DataNode process is set to be the main process and the ConfigNode process is set to be the backstage process. The DataNode main process needs to be connected to the Confignode backstage process, so the system may need to wait for a while. You can use `stop-confignode.sh` to stop ConfigNode and trigger a snapshot, so that the restart process will be faster.